# Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to List<String> attempting to populate a dropdown

Tags: java

I am attempting to populate a dropdown from the controller by passing the iteration value to a list. The iteration is done successfully but I keep getting a type mismatch error

```
List<Skills> mskills = skillsService.getAll();

for(Skills skills : mskills ){
    String nameVal =  skills.getName();
    List<String> matchName = nameVal; //having an issue here
}

return matchName;
```

how can pass the value of **nameVal** to the **matchName**. Kindly assist

Comment: maybe ``matchName.add(nameVal)`` ?

Comment: List<String> matchName <-- this is a list.
In order to add item to the list You need to use 
matchName.add(nameVal);
I'd recommend : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/

Comment: This is a basic java issue (assignement)! you must learn before applying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few mistakes. `matchName` list is not visible out of the for loop. Further more, you can't assign a String to a List reference.

Replace your code with:

```
List<Skills> mskills = skillsService.getAll();
List<String> matchName = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Skills skills : mskills ){
        String nameVal =  skills.getName();
        matchName.add(nameVal); //having an issue here
    }
return matchName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign a `String` object to a `List<String>` object. You need to create a list and then add elements to it.

```
List<Skills> matchName = new ArrayList<>();
List<Skills> mSkills = skillService.getAll();
for(Skill s : mSkills) {
   String nameVal = skills.getName();
   matchName.add(nameVal);
}
return matchName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<String> matchName = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Skills skills : mskills ){
    String nameVal =  skills.getName();
    matchName.add(nameVal); //having an issue here
}
return matchName;
```